# python: reset partial function argument

Tags: python

Is there a way to reset a python partial argument, without having to redefine the partial function itself?

For example, I would like to be able to reset the accumulator below:

```
accum = []
def accumulator(list, item):
    list.append(item)

a = partial(accumulator, accum)
a(5)
a(7)
accum
```

which prints `[5, 7]` as expected. Now I want to reset the list to empty, but maintain the defined behavior on `a`:

```
accum = []
a(8)
accum
```

I would expect `[8]` but this time, i get an empty list instead. Is there a way to maintain the connection between the defined function and the variable in the outer scope?

Comment: Not that I am aware off. You can see the args, with `a.args` but this is a readonly attribute. Note: don't call your arg `list` it hides pythons builtin `list` type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`partial` binds objects, not variables; `a` has a reference to the list object that `accum` referred to, not a reference to the `accum` variable. Assigning to `accum` will only rebind the `accum` reference, not the one in the `partial` object.

While you can clear the list object:

```
accum.clear()
```

or before Python 3.3:

```
del accum[:]
```

this whole setup with a mutable object bound with `partial` seems like a recipe for weird aliasing and statefulness bugs. I'd recommend a different approach to whatever underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Actually there might be cases where you wouldn't want to write a function but you do want a function with a state (OOP). Still it is not recommended not readable not maintainable might surprise user etc

Answer (score 1):

Python is creating a closure, meaning that partial returns a function `a` which holds a pointer to the list `accum` at lets say 0x1 in the memory.

now you are creating a new list at 0x2 and replacing the pointer in variable accum. the function is still looking at 0x1.

You can use

```
accum.clear()
```

which will give your wanted behaviour.

Comment: It's not a closure. A closure actually *would* have been affected by reassigning `accum`.

Comment: @user2357112 you are mistaken (or maybe they teach differently where you are from). closure will keep the environment needed for the function to run. In this case it is a list object which becomes out of scope for the user code but not for the function, you are talking about the pointer to he list object which the closure does not hold.

Comment: Closures remember variables, not objects. [Here's how it would look with a closure.](https://ideone.com/lBYiN4)

Comment: Can be value or reference. In your example accum is still in scope so it is by reference (probably didn't go to spec of python to be sure). Anyway you can see here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, the approach your taking is probably not a good idea.  One way to accomplish what i *think* you are after is to use a closure:

```
def accumulator():
    acc = [] #each time you call accumulator, you have a new list
    def inner(item):
        acc.append(item) #that list is shared on each call of the returned inner
        return acc
    return inner

foo = accumulator()

print(foo(2))
print(foo(3))
print(foo(4))

bar = accumulator()
print(bar(9))
```

Comment: Performing `b = accumulator(8,list())` does not cause the new list to be used for future calls to `accumulator`.

Comment: Oops - yeah dumb mistake.  Editing to clean it up.

Comment: Your code works now, but the question did say "without having to redefine the partial function itself". I think the creation of the new `bar` goes against that.

Comment: Yes, you are right - still I think this is a safer alternative and likely accomplishes the same result.